# What does 'request.GET.get' in an API creation do in Django and how does it work precisely?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm watching a lecture about Django. The lecturer explains everything wonderfully but didn't go into much detail into "an API I effectively created". This is my first time meddling with this so I'm a bit unsure.

What I don't understand is specifically this line `request.GET.get("start")`. How does one make that work in the index.html file (with embedded js script) by just using a fetch?

views.py

```
def posts(request):
    # Get start and end points
    start = int(request.GET.get("start") or 0)
    end = int(request.GET.get("end") or (start + 9))
    
    # Generate list of posts
    data = []
    for i in range(start, end + 1):
        data.append(f"Post #{i}")
    
    # Artificially delay speed of response
    time.sleep(1)

    # Return list of posts
    return JsonResponse({
        "posts": data
    })
```

index.html

```
    fetch(`/posts?start=${start}&end=${end}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
       data.posts.forEach(add_post);
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

The **request** object contains information about the user's request. What data they've sent to the page, where they are coming from, etc.

**request.GET** contains the GET variables. These are what you see in your browser's address bar. The **.get()** method is a method used for dictionaries. What your snippet of code is doing is saying, "*Get the value of a GET variable with name 'page*', and if it doesn't exist, return 1".

Likewise, you will see request.POST used when a user submits a form.

For the specific example posted:
start = int(request.GET.get(**"start"**) or 0)
end = int(request.GET.get(**"end"**) or (start + 9))

fetch(`/posts?start=${start}&end=${end}`)

eg. http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts?start=10&end=20
This will fetch post#10 to post#20 from the API.

You can change these start & end variable to first and last or anything else it would work same.